# changeDate event for vanilla-js inline datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I recently found this library, vanilla-js datepicker (https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/) and I'm trying to use the inline picker.

Example:

```
<div id="foo" data-date="01/25/2020"></div>

const elem = document.getElementById('foo');

const datepicker = new Datepicker(elem, {
  // ...options
});
```

So far, so good, I have the picker showing in my site.

My problem is that I can't get the date on change, according to the documentation (https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/api?id=events) for the inline datepicker I should get the block-element, that would be `<div id="foo" data-date="01/25/2020"></div>` and there is an event called changeDate (https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/api?id=changedate).

So, according to that, I figure that this is the code that I should work on:

```
elem.addEventListener('changeDate', (e) => {
    console.log('Date selected');
  })
```

I also tried

```
datepicker.addEventListener('changeDate', (e) => {
    console.log('Date selected');
  })
```

But no, is not working for me, this might be taken as a repeat question but the examples here works for the input type datepickers but not for the inline one.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, since I'm also working with EditorJS to make a custom block, I wasn't targeting the element in the right way.

```
  this.wrapper.querySelector(elem).addEventListener('changeDate', (e) => {
    console.log(this.datePicker.getDate());
  })
```

This code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you need to target the `element` of `datepicker`.

```
datepicker.element.addEventListener('changeDate', (e) => {
    console.log('Date selected');
  })
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/mena234/pen/LYrLrNv?editors=1111)